# Pandas replace with regex

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I'm trying to remove a `¹` symbol from a string using pandas replace with regex. How I do that?
From:
`Some string¹`
To:`Some string`

Something like that?
`df.replace({"column":{'*¹':''}},  regex=True)`

Comment: Just `df.replace({"column":{'¹':''}},  regex=True)` without `*` (this is a special regex character), and don't forget to assign the output

Comment: Just forgot to ```df_update = df.replace({"column":{'*¹':''}},  regex=True)```

Comment: `'*¹` is invalid if you use `regex=True` as there is nothing to repeat before `*`. If you use `'.*¹` this will remove everything before the `¹` (included)